# why am i getting this error while running vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

i am creating a project
i am using vue Cli
i installed npm, vue 3.2.26
i ran npm serve run which was very good.form the command prompt.
NOW
i tried the same with ui
but on running task it gives an error

> Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or
> @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree.
>
> Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc
> to be present in the dependency tree.
> at Object. (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/compiler.js:14:15)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at Object. (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js:29:20)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at /mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js:154:16
> at /mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:268:40
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:268:26)
> at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:272:48)
> at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:132:25)
> at serve (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:79:31)
> at Service.run (/mnt/c/Users/admin/Documents/practice3/vue/test/vue_crash_todolist/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:262:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

when i look at the dependencies
[image]

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You're using Vue CLI but have Vite plugin in deps for some reason